# Как работает связывание данных в AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Как работает связывание данных в AngularJS?

Я не нашел подробного описания на этом [сайте](https://angularjs.org/).

1. Как AngularJS отслеживает изменения свойств модели без сеттеров и
   геттеров?
2. Как AngularJS узнаёт что я изменил, например, следующую переменную и
   отображает это изменение в представлении?

   ```
   $scope.myobject = { myproperty : 'old value' };
   myobject.myproperty = 'new value';
   ```

Comment: Вы уверены в истинности второго высказывания? Если в $scope или $rootScope нету ссылки на myobject то AngularJS и не узнаёт ничего.

Comment: а зачем ждать? если Вы знаете ответ то можете его дать сами и получить заслуженную награду в виде *репы*, или же перевести ответ, это тоже не запрещено

Comment: Просим ответ :) Интересно это.

Comment: _Я не нашел подробного описания на этом сайте._ - а оно там есть, просто несколько больших разделов

Comment: _есть отличные ответы на английском стековерфлоу._ - как вариант, можно их попереводить, с указанием источника. [Переводы поддерживаются](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/70/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8B-%D1%81-%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-so)

Comment: @MasterAlex, 0.10 довольно сильно отличается от 1.5.8 которая сейчас

Comment: @Max, если тебе не важен ответ на вопрос, может его и задавать тогда не стоит?

Answer (score 2):

Angular запоминает значение и сравнивает его с предыдущим значением. Если происходит изменение в значении, то он запускает событие изменения.

**1. Наблюдатели**

Angular поддерживает простой список watсhers(наблюдатели), который содержится в объектах $scope. Если вы проверите в своем приложении любой $scope, то вы заметите в нем такое поле $$watchers.

Каждый watсher(наблюдатель) это объект который состоит из следующего:

1. Выражение которое проверяет watсher. Это может быть именем атрибута объекта или что-то более сложное;
2. Последнее известное значение выражения. Это значение можно сравнить со значением текущего вычисленного выражения. Если значения отличаются, то watсher будет вызывать функцию(см. ниже), а также же $scope будет отмечен как грязный(dirty).
3. Функция которая будет выполнена, если наблюдаемое выражение изменилось.

**2. Способы создания наблюдателей**

Существуют различные способы для определения наблюдателей:

1. Вы можете явно определить watсher как атрибут $scope:

   ```
   $scope.$watch('person.username', validateUnique);
   ```

   Где `validateUnique` это функция которая будет вызвана, если изменится значение поля `person.username`.
2. Вы можете поместить свое выражение в фигурные скобки в шаблоне(watсher будет создан для текущего $scope автоматически):

   ```
   <p>username: {{person.username}}</p>
   ```
3. Вы можете определить директиву, такую как ng-model, ng-repeat:

   ```
   <input ng-model="person.username" />
   ```

**3. Цикл  $digest**

При запуске вашего angular приложения, запускается цикл $digest.

В цикле $digest выполняются еще два цикла. Один из циклов обрабатывает очередь $evalAsync, второй — список $watch. Цикл $digest выполняется до тех пор, пока значение вашего выражения не синхронизируется. Это означает, что $evalAsync опустошится, а в $watch не останется никаких изменений.

Цикл $digest представляет собой обход $scope и всех его дочерних облостей видимости. Для каждого $scope будет перебираться его массив $$watchers и для каждого элемента будет произведена оценка его выражения(изменилось ли оно). Если новое значение выражения отличается от последнего известного, то вызывается функция наблюдателя. Эта функция может перекомпилировать часть DOM, переписать значение в $scope, вызвать AJAX запрос и т.д.

**4. Что происходит если watсher срабатывает**

Если watсher срабатывает то приложение знает, что что-то изменилось и $scope помечается как грязный(dirty).

Функции наблюдателей могут изменять другие переменные текущего или родительского $scope, поэтому цикл $digest будет вызван снова. Это позволяет гарантировать, что в итоге все $scope будут синхронизированы(значения всех отслеживаемых выражений буду такими же как и в предидущей итерации цикла $digest). Но такое поведение цикла $digest могло бы вызвать зацикливание, поэтому по умолчанию он может быть вызван до 10 раз подряд, пока все $scope не будут отмечены как чистые. Если этот лимит превышен, то мы увидим такую ошибку в консоли:

```
10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
```

**5. Производительность.**

Как вы можете видеть, при любых изменениях в приложении, чтобы понять как реагировать, angular будет проверять каждый отдельный watсher во всей иерархии $scope.

С точки зрения разработчика это очень производительно, так как не нужно задумываться о там как отслеживать изменения выражений и отображать их в шаблоне. Если выражение изменилось, то Angular просто заменит его.

С точки зрения машины это очень не эффективно и это будет тормозить ваше приложение.

С точки зрения человека:

- *Медленно* — Все, что происходит быстрее, чем за 50мс незаметно для человека. Таким образом, 50мс можно считать как "моментально".
- *Ограничено* — Вы не можете реально показать больше чем, примерно, 2000 единиц информации человеку на одной странице. Если у вас на странице количество информации больше, чем это значение, то на самом деле это плохое UI, и пользователи не могут обработать это в любом случае.

Таким образом, реальный вопрос заключается в следующем: Сколько сравнений вы можете сделать в браузере за 50мс? Это сложный вопрос, поскольку многие факторы вступают в игру. Вот [тест](http://jsperf.com/angularjs-digest/6), который создает 10000 наблюдателей. В современном браузере это занимает менее 6мс. В Internet Explorer 8 - около 40мс. Как вы можете видеть, это не проблема, даже для старых браузеров. Существует один нюанс: Сравнения должны быть простыми, чтобы вписаться в лимит по времени. К сожалению, слишком легко добавить медленные сравнения в ваше приложение, так что очень легко построить медленное приложение, когда вы не знаете точно, что вы делаете.

**6. Одноразовое связывание**

Добиться большей производительности можно за счет использования одноразового связывания. Такие выражения будут записаны в шаблоне вашего приложения один раз и не будут отслеживаться в цикле $digest, соответственно мы получаем прирост в производительности и можем отвести место в цикле $digest для более важных выражений. Если вы знаете, что какие-то элементы вашего приложения создаются в вашем шаблоне единожды и больше не изменяются, то одноразовое связывание это то, что вам нужно. Простой пример одноразового связывания:

```
<h1>{{ ::title }}</h1>
```

Источник: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9682092/how-does-data-binding-work-in-angularjs

Comment: `one-time binding` - это не одностороннее, а скорее одноразовое связывание

Comment: пункт "производительность" лучше вообще выкинуть, либо сузить до одно предложения: много наблюдателей - плохо.

Comment: вообще, получилась попытка ответить на все сразу в одно месте, в итоге, по верхам и половина не до конца. Лучше конкретизировать и сам вопрос, и сам ответ. Конкретно, стоило больше уделить внимания наблюдателям и их работе. Как минимум не хватает описания `$watchCollection`, нет описания что возвращают эти функции и как вообще работают

Comment: По поводу производительности, все было взято [отсюда](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9682092/how-does-data-binding-work-in-angularjs). Я считаю, что это важно знать, когда речь идет о связывании в ангуларе.

Comment: Раз уж это был перевод, как я понимаю не одного ответа, стоило указать ссылки на источник. В любом случае, если сравнить твой ответ с тем, что по ссылки, у тебя он получился более широким. И это не очень хорошо.

Comment: Ну и сам перевод не очень, совсем непонятно что имелось ввиду тут: люди: медленно -... ограниченно-...

Comment: Поправил, пишите, если что-то еще не понятно, я поправлю

Comment: Пункт производительность - никуда не годится: тесту три года, сам тест ничего не показывает, рассуждения о 50мс, высосаны из пальца, опять же: все сводится к одному предложению - использовать простые watch, без сложных сравнений, либо вообще обойтись без них. Список способов создать watch неполон: в нем все еще нет watchCollection, с описанием чем он отличается. Нет описания третьего параметра `watch`. Нет описания возвращаемого значения и примера его использования.

Comment: Стоит так же обратить внимание, что в исходном вопросе все описание работы вместилось в два абзаца, и далее шло сравнение подхода dirty-checking с подходами в других фреймворках.

Comment: а, вижу что это несколько ответов собранных вместе. Стоит добавить ссылку на все используемые. Либо выбрать какой-нибудь один, а не пытаться уместить все в одном месте